# STM32 - changing HAL_UART_Receive_IT size if flag is true - makes it not callback anymore

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, dma

I need to read from an uart port which will output very small amounts of data, however I don't know how many characters it will output. It works using AT commands...

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, A_Buffer, A_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, SCBK_Buffer, 1);
```

While I am sending commands I need to read the response, for this my approach was to read byte by byte, however when it is connected I don't need to read every byte but every 64 (would be enough)

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  MSGQUEUE_OBJ_t msg;
  osStatus_t status;

  //usart 1 works fine - as expected
  if (huart->Instance == USART1)
  {
      memcpy(msg.msg, A_Buffer, sizeof(APS_Buffer));
      status = osMessageQueuePut(A_HandlerHandle, &msg, 0U, 0U);
      return;
  }
  if (huart->Instance == USART3)
  {
      memcpy(msg.msg, SCBK_Buffer, sizeof(SCBK_Buffer));
      status = osMessageQueuePut(SCBK_HandlerHandle, &msg, 0U, 0U);
      HAL_StatusTypeDef x;

      if(isConnected)
      {
          x = HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, SCBK_Buffer, SCBK_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
      }
      else
      {
          x = HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, SCBK_Buffer, 1);
      }


      return;
  }
}
```

x is just for me to debug and ensure that it is returning HAL_OK.

After it connects and falls under the if statement, the callback won't ever be called again for that uart port.

Comment: HAL handling of those peripherals is simply bad. Write it bare registers

Comment: @0___________ can you give me an example? I'm not sure what bare registers are and what changes I may need to do on my code

Comment: did you read reference manual?

Comment: As 0___________ says, it is unlikely that you can use the HAL UART implementation as it is for anything serious. To get more understanding, you should read the reference manual (UART peripheral section) and look into the HAL implementation.
You could also try to implement `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback` to see if that is called in your case.